# In issue with ClassCastException while extending File class

Tags: java, arrays, casting

I've a small but too difficult for me to find out problem concerning extending File class by my own MyFile class. The point is to make a method that would recursively find files in a folder tree. However , I've stumbled upon a problem which is a ClassCastException at the point of calling listFilesRecurse() of type MyFile on files casted to MyFile. I've been thinking about my approch and sadly it seems quite reasonable... I'd be very grateful is somebody of you guys helped me.

```
public class MyFile extends File {

    public MyFile(String  s) {
        super(s);
    }

    public List <File> listFilesRecurse() {
        List <File> finalList = new ArrayList<File>();

        File [] tab =   this.listFiles();
        for (File tab1 : tab) {
            if (tab1.isFile()) {
                finalList.add(tab1);
            } else if (tab1.isDirectory()) {
                ((MyFile) tab1).listFilesRecurse();
            }
        }

    return finalList;
    }
}
```

I didn't realize the rules of inheritance and now I've came up with a working version.

```
public class MyFile {

String path;
public MyFile (String path) {
    this.path = path;
}

List <File> list = new ArrayList<File> ();
List <String> nameList = new ArrayList <String> ();

 List <File> listFilesRecusive() {

    File f = new File(path);

    File [] files = f.listFiles();

    for (File fil : files) {

        String subFile = fil.getName();

        if (fil.isFile()) {
        list.add(fil);
        nameList.add(fil.getName());
    } else if (fil.isDirectory()) {
        this.path = fil.toString();
        this.listFilesRecusive();

    }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Cast does not convert an object from one class to another.  All it does is assert that the object is of that class (or is a subclass of that class).  If that assertion is untrue you get ClassCastException.

Answer (score 4):

**What you're doing actually doesn't make too much sense.**

When you do

```
this.listFiles();
```

It is actually returning real File instances from the base class method.  The base class has no idea that you made a derived class, and the file instances it returns cannot possibly be casted to the derived class.

**Possible Solution**

You could create a MyFile from the existing files with a constructor, but casting is out of the question.  So, create a constructor in MyFile that takes a File instance, and use that instead of the cast.

Comment: Thank U very much for help, I thought that 'this' refers to MyClass object while the 'super' keyword rather refers to the base class. :)

Comment: And just btw: so how should I access the only argument of the object which I call a method on? Shuld I make some fields in the class or what?

Answer (score 2):

The `java.io` API knows nothing about your class. The (inherited) method `listFiles()` returns `File` objects. This line:

```
((MyFile) tab1).listFilesRecurse();
```

has a cast that fails because a `File` is not a `MyFile`.

To make your idea "work", you would have to override `listFiles()` (and every other method that returns `File` objects) to return `MyFile` objects instead.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about the mechanism of inheritance but in terms of overriding methods - I know how to do it but just out of curiosity - is there any way to look into a source code of predefined methods using Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, you can see the source by downloading and installing the JDK and using that as the Eclipse runtime, then attach src.zip as source

Answer (score 1):

You are casting down from `File` to `MyFile`. Thats the reason for the `ClassCastException`.

You can work around this by first creating a `MyFile` object in your loop iteration and then using it instead.

I think you might want to re-think why you are extending File in the first place and instead, provide utility via a static method or composition.

Answer (score 0):

**`File` is not `MyFile`.**

The method `.listFiles()` returns a list of `File`, the error is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A {
}

class B extends A {
}

A a = new B();
B b = (B) a;
```

Is valid, but:

```
A a = new A();
B b = (B) a;
```

Will throw a `ClassCastException`.